# Does the dpi number reported by camera in JPG have any meaning?

Tags: sensor, metadata, jpeg, dpi

I have two cameras, a 6mpix Panasonic FZ8, and 14mpix Canon A2200.

When I compare shots from two cameras, one of differences I notice is
dpi number that camera reports in JPG info:

- FZ8 reports dpi=72
- A2200 reports dpi=180

What physical meaning can these numbers have? I am at loss for guesses.

I am fairly familiar with notion of dpi in scanning and printing. I can calculate density of pixels on the sensor of the camera. But then, the linear density of pixels on the sensor will be hundreds times larger than number above. So what, if anything, does it mean?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4779/confused-about-dpis-large-jpg-file-to-print and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/what-does-dpi-mean. I don't think we've got this straightforward question covered directly though. (So, +1!)

Comment: Well right. I am not asking what *is* DPI.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The values written in JPEG files are arbitrary and essentially meaningless. They don't relate to anything about the camera, its sensor, or the resulting images. They certainly don't relate to image quality or acceptable resolution for printing. Really, they mostly serve to confuse people.

The [EXIF standard](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) seems to imply that if the tag is missing, 72 is the (still-meaningless) default. However, it is apparently mandatory for the [TIFF standard](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/content/tiff_tags.shtml), from which the JPEG/EXIF format basically inherits everything. So maybe it has to have some value to properly comply with the standard.

Others have noted that some desktop publishing or word processing software reads this value and will use it for default scaling on the page. So, I guess in that sense, there is "meaning", but I'd argue that this is really *misapplication*, because the original value doesn't have meaning. Garbage in, garbage out, as the saying goes.

Now, maybe in an alternate universe the standard could relate to a standard print size. Or, the camera could estimate real detail in the image and give a recommended maximum print size. But none of that is the case. **In practice, these values are meaningless and you should ignore them, even if some software makes assumptions based on them when opening files.**

Comment: I realize now that for images coming from scanner, dpi field carries real meaning, so that's why that field is there.

Comment: I think the 72 dpi number comes from the CRT days. AFAIR, this was the average dot pitch of CRT monitors back then, so it is not totally meaningless.

Comment: Sure, not totally _arbitrary_ in origin, but I'm going to stick to saying that it's meaningless in this context.

Comment: For a historical perspective -- in print layout workflows a dpi number is used (or is supposed to be used) as a guide to how large the image can be on the printed page. If you set a 200 dpi value (common for newspapers) for a 2000x1000 pixel image the person placing the image in the page layout software (who is normally not a photographer) would be told that the image is 10x5 inches. The same image with a dpi set to 72 would seem to be about 28x14 inches -- but if the editor actually used it at that size the image would appear pixelated.

Comment: @David: sounds reasonable in theory, but the numbers actually put by the camera in JPEG files (refer up to the question) aren't being used that way. It'd be interesting if camera makers had decided to set this number based on a reasonable estimation of image quality for the sensor at the given ISO, or something like that. But they don't.

Comment: As far as today's digital cameras go and the workflow of most photographers -- right, the numbers are random and bogus. I was just pointing out the use of the dpi values in the print publishing industry to show why they exist at all. Unless I'm terribly mistaken metadata attached to digital images pre-dates DSLR cameras and the layout of the original metadata was designed for news services, like the Associated Press.

Comment: So is an application that **actually renders an image using the color profile in the image's metadata** rather than ignoring it and instead rendering it based on the application's preferred color profile also considered a *misapplication?*

Comment: @MichaelClark If cameras attached a vestigial color profile that had no relation to the colors recorded by the camera, and applications used that anyway, yeah, that'd be a misapplication.

Comment: I fail to understand why you consider that a PPI value in an image's metadata has no relation to an image. The standards organizations that govern the interoperability of digital images still requires them. Just because *all* or even *most* applications that handle images may or may not use that value does not mean that an image no longer needs to have such a value to comply with *established standards* that have been and continue to be used by *some* applications that do use them.

Comment: Arbitrarily saying such values are *totally meaningless* and that software that use them are *making assumptions* when including such a value in the metadata of images is required by international standards organizations and using those values by document creators is compliant with the *established standards* for digital images is a bit like saying "copyright laws are meaningless because no one followed them on Napster."

Comment: Uh, no, it is not at all like that. The values are required by the standards but *are meaningless in this context*. Are to really suggesting that it's somehow correct *in a meaningful way* that the images from the Panasonic camera and the Canon camera be displayed at those specific sizes?

Comment: And they have no relationship to the image because camera makers put arbitrary values there, not ones which relate to anything of significance.

Comment: @MichaelClark If you claim that the dpi value is not meaningless *in the context of a digital photo*, then you need to explain what the meaning is. The term obviously stands for *dots per inch*, so the question is: inches of what? With a scanned image, the number makes sense: it means the number of dots read per linear inch of the scanned page. For a photo, though, it can't refer to inches of the original object, since that depends on camera distance, and it doesn't mean inches of the sensor, which wouldn't be helpful anyway. So: inches of what?

Comment: @Caleb That's simple: inches of space on a page when that page is printed according to the *International Standards* that apply to the metadata contained in digital images.

Comment: @mattdm They're *not* meaningless in the context of desktop publishing. That's one of the uses of digital images for which provision is made by the committees that determine *International Standards* for such digital images.

Comment: **The particular values set by the camera are still meaningless even in the context of desktop publishing.**

Comment: @mattdm That is blatantly incorrect. If the value set by the camera is unchanged, that is the value used when the image is imported into any page setting application, or even many document creation applications. Sure, it can be resized after it is imported, but the original value still has meaning when it is first imported. Saying just because it can be changed means it has no meaning is like saying the photographic information in a photo has no meaning because one can use a "stamping" tool to change it, or that the date/time captured has no meaning because it can be changed after the fact.

Comment: I've worked on a newspaper. Never once did that value have any practical meaning. There's a space on the page that the photo is going into, and that's what matters, not the size the image is scaled to by the DPI value. I can't imagine any other situation where it *would* be important.

Comment: And your stamping tool comparison is blatantly silly. The date is maybe a better analogy, but **it's like every camera set that to 1970-01-01 or 2000-01-01 (chosen arbitrarily by the manufacturer), and you're claiming that it's somehow important that photos show up on a timeline at those points.** These values are arbitrary and meaningless in every context; even if you think of them as "default scaling values" they are arbitrary and meaningless default scaling values.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience those numbers have no special meaning. The camera makers just pick one and use it in all their firmware.

Comment: I just noticed that the Olympus OM-D E-M5 has a menu option to select your _own_ arbitrary value. Given everything else I'm not sure that's really a _useful_ option, but there it is!

Answer (score 4):

The number is just a random filler. It has no significance since the camera does not know how big you will print.

Most cameras default to 72 which according to the EXIF standard is the default value. Some cameras let you set it yourself. Then again, it has little meaning unless you will print all your images without cropping exactly at the same size.

Comment: Print, or view on-screen for that matter.

Comment: I don't think printing is where the DPI should (theoretically) resolve from. This is a photo, so the dimensions of the field-of-view of the camera, divided by the resolution, would be the *actual* dpi of the photo.

Comment: Therefore, it seems to me that if you know the angle of view of the camera's lens, and the camera had some manner of ranging facility (ultrasonic?) to measure the distance to what it is pointing at, the values could be populated with a (rough, perhaps) meaningful value.

Comment: @Fake Name - How about just using the focus-distance? As a matter of fact, you can probably write a small program that does this after the fact if your camera stores the focus-distance in the EXIF (only some do unfortunately).

Comment: @Fake Name - but in a typical image, each pixel records an object at a different depth. So, the conversion will be correct only at a small amount of pixels? Do you suggest that for the same lens-sensor configuration (FoV), two images of a person in different distances will produce different dpi values? I think the best that you can do following your idea is to state the Dots-per-Radian (DPR) or -Degree (DPD) which is the angular spatial resolution of your system.

Comment: ... and DPR/DPD becomes problematic as well when dealing with wide-angle lenses.

Comment: @ysap - `but in a typical image, each pixel records an object at a different depth. So, the conversion will be correct only at a small amount of pixels?` - The idea is for the data to be correct for the pixels that are *in focus*, since they are generally the part of the image that is of interest. Obviously, the greater the DOF, the less value there is in the resulting number.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the JPEG file as a document, the divide the pixel count in the image by the DPI number and you get the Print Size of the image. 
This of course results meaningless as many printing systems re-size the image arbitrarily. However, there still are printing mechanisms in which the print size is given by such parameters. 
If you have Photoshop, go to the resize image dialog and uncheck the re-sample option. You'll observe that changing any size of the image will change the dpi number. 
Curiously I'm in the case where I have to print some images and the lab providing the service won't do ANY resizing for me, so I have to re-sample the images to a specific resolution and DPI number.
Another use of this number is that it will allow a better approximation of how big you can print an image without distorting too much for your working parameters.
So, in your case, your cameras are just setting a default print size for your images. But unless your printing service relies on this for the size, I see no other use for it and it says nothing about your sensor, so a comparison there is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

> What physical meaning can these numbers have?

The [EXIF standard](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) doesn't actually have a single `dpi` field, but it does have `XResolution` and `YResolution` fields, and these are where the dpi value displayed by most software comes from. The standard doesn't say specifically whether those values apply to the image source, e.g. a scanned document, or destination, e.g. a printed copy of the image, but since the entity that *writes* the metadata knows where the image comes from but can't know how it will be used, the only reasonable interpretation is that those fields relate to the image source.

The standard *does* say that if the value for the `XResolution` and `YResolution` tags is unknown, then `72` should be used. One could reasonably argue that this was a poor choice, since `72` is a valid value whose meaning shouldn't be overloaded. It probably would've made more sense to choose a value that couldn't possibly represent a real resolution, such as `0` or `-1`, to mean "unknown." But that's not what the standard says, and so if your image has `72` for the resolution fields, you simply can't know whether the metadata writer knew what resolution to use or not.

The problem is compounded by the fact that some cameras set a value other than `72` when they can't really know what resolution the subject was recorded at, since that varies depending on how far away the camera was from he subject. Those camera manufacturers might have been trying to use the resolution fields to suggest a reasonable print resolution, but this only confuses the meaning of the resolution fields.

If you're trying to actually learn something about an image, you'll be better off using the `FocalPlaneXResolution` and `FocalPlaneYResolution` fields, which record the sensor resolution at which the image was recorded. And of course the `ImageWidth` and `ImageLength` fields will tell you the dimensions of the image in pixels.

Answer (score -1):

> Does the dpi number reported by camera in JPG have any meaning?

Yes. It means the jpeg image is compliant with the *International Standards* agreed upon by camera makers and others with an interest in the production  and use of digital images.

**In most current digital environments the DPI reported by the camera in the image metadata has no real meaning.**

The applications we use to look at a photo on our screens will almost always scale an image to fit a particular space on the screen.

The printers most of us use will almost always automatically scale an image to fit on a specified size of paper.

**But there is still one notable exception: Desktop publishing.** Page setting software such as InDesign and even most word processing programs still "think" in actual physical dimensions. That's why such applications usually show a scale at the top and/or sides of the page that shows the width and length of the page in inches or centimeters.

If we have two version of an image that is 720 pixels wide and the only difference between the two is the "PPI" reported in the image metadata, here's what happens when we insert both into a document that measures things in real inches/centimeters:

[image]

Remember, the actual pixels in both images are *identical*, the only difference is in the "DPI" value reported by the images metadata. In this case the reported "PPI" *does* affect how large the image appears on a "page" in the document or on an actual page when the document printed.

Comment: the values written in the field by the camera are still nonsensical and apparently completely arbitrary (comparing the two from the OP) considering that the camera can't know how large you'd like to print the image.

Comment: The fact that your desktop publishing software tries to interpret the resolution tag in a useful way doesn't mean that the meaning it chooses corresponds to the intent of whatever wrote the image. Furthermore, it's entirely possible that two different desktop publishing programs could choose different interpretations of the value for the very same photo. You may not agree that the meaning of the `XResolution` and `YResolution` tags are meaningless, but you have to admit that the tags are at least ambiguous, and that requiring them is a flaw in the EXIF standard.

Comment: @Calab You can believe that they are ambiguous, or that requiring them is a flaw in the EXIF standard, but you still must admit that they are required by that standard as well as the fact that if no value is present there's nothing for applications (designed specifically to work with *compliant* files) to interpret.