# Photo resolution for a large canvas

Tags: lightroom, resolution, canvas

I'm trying to resize a photo taken with a Canon 5D Mark III for a 36" X 72" canvas at 300ppi through Lightroom 5. I exported the photo at H: 10800 X W: 21600, but the printing company is telling me that the resolution is still too small. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a suitable image resolution for canvas prints?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19678/what-is-a-suitable-image-resolution-for-canvas-prints)

Comment: Did you verify that the exported image actually had those dimensions? I'm not familiar with Lightroom's behavior, but some software will only use the dimensions you give for *downscaling*, and will do no resizing if the image is already smaller than the specified size.

Comment: It has TOTALLY no sense on resampling an image like that! Send the original file!

Comment: 10800 x 21600 is 230 megapixels, your camera has 22 megapixels

Answer (score 2):

We already have quite a few answers on this topic, so you should do some reading at least here:

- [Is there a general formula for image size vs. print size?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/456/is-there-a-general-formula-for-image-size-vs-print-size)
- [What is a suitable image resolution for canvas prints?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19678/what-is-a-suitable-image-resolution-for-canvas-prints)

The short of it is that you should not resize anything on your side. Let the printer do that for you. Send them the largest image you have before you have tried any resizing. It should work just fine for what you are doing(assuming up to 72 *inches*) if the image was from a 5D MkIII.

Comment: But... the question implies that the printers *aren't* going to do that for them, and have said so.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle Yes I agree that it implies that. The issue I believe is user error and not any printer shortcomings.

Comment: I can not understate the importance of this: "The short of it is that you should not resize anything on your side"... (Is that a correct use of understate? :o)