# How do I convert multiple RAW files to jpeg in Photoshop Elements 11 without losing the RAW?

Tags: photoshop, raw

I've just started shooting in RAW. Could someone please tell me how to process and save multiple RAW photos to jpeg in Photoshop Elements 11 while keeping the raw file format (dng) file?

I open the Photoshop editor and go to process multiple files. But it does not save the original RAW (DNG) file), and once I save it as a jpeg, the photo compresses. 
What concerns me is that I know I just lost the original RAW file and if I need to edit the processed file it will keep compressing.  After it's saved as a JPEG it's compressed from a 20 megapixel file to 8-10 megapixel file.  I shoot portraits and my clients need to be able to print the files for wall art.

I have also tried going to the Organizer to open, select, and edit the files in RAW format, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why do you think the DNG file is lost?

Comment: when I do a multiple batch in photoshop elements and save as a jpeg. the dng file is gone. and the file states raw.jpeg. the original file or raw file is gone. the only way I can keep it as a raw file is open up photoshop process each photo individual thru the raw format. which is a pain especially when you have a 1000 photos to edit.

Comment: I don't have Photoshop Elements, but I think I know what it might be. First, if you rename a `.raw.jpeg` file back to just `.raw` and open it, what file type is it? Second, if you *uncheck* the rename box in the Process Multiple Files dialog and run a small batch, what happens?

Comment: Actually, in any case, can you please post a screenshot of that dialog with exactly the settings you are using? I think that might help others figure out the answer.

Comment: it doesn't let me do a screen shot or attach anything on here. when I did a batch edit. it saved it to a jpeg file and then I have .dng file. but after I did the batch edit and it changed to a jpeg file. the file went from 20 megapixel raw file to a 8-10 megapixel jpeg file. in other words does anyone know how to do edit multiple raw photos and save them to a jpeg while still being able to keep it as a raw file so I can still edit the file and without compressing it.

Comment: also how do you process high resolution disk? I know I can change all the raw files to 300 resolution. but it looks like you can't print 20x30 or larger print at 300 resolution.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't add a screenshot (I thought new users can, now) but if you can put it somewhere else, I'll inline it for you.)

Comment: Note that you are confusing "megapixel" and "megabyte". But the further confusion is that the thing you are asking to do — preserving the originals — is ... the normal thing it does.

Comment: Also, on the quesiton about "300 resolution", see 
[Does the dpi number reported by camera in JPG have any meaning?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/) — the answer is that it does not. It's just a suggestion for display, and does not affect your ability to print at any size. (It's actually the number of megapixels that's important — the pixel dimensions of the image, not the file size (in megabytes) that matters for print detail, although there's really [no hard rule](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/456/is-there-a-general-formula-for-image-size-vs-print-size).)

Answer (score 3):

If you open a file, and save it as a different file type, you have now *a second file*. The original dng file is still where it was when you opened it, and you can reprocess it as often as you want, just like a negative doesn't self destruct when you make a print from it.

The other confusion you seem to have is regarding megapixels and megabyte. The number of pixels doesn't change unless you crop or resize your image. What changes when you save in a compressed format like JPEG is the size of the *file* on disk, expressed in bytes. 20 megabytes for a DNG sounds about right, 8-10 megabyte for a JPEG is on the large side, presumably you saved at highest quality setting.

Answer (score -3):

may i give a new solution

in a notepad

enter the following

```
ren *.RAW *.JPG
copy *.JPG *.RAW
```

then save the file as convert.bat in the same folder of the image

and double click the convert.bat.

this converst the raw files to jpeg then copies the jpeg and save it as .RAW files again.
it uses Command prompt in windows to execute the command.

Comment: This will now work.  It is not simply a rename to convert from raw to jpeg.  You could also accomplish the same thing with only a copy operation.  The rename and then copy is an extra step in addition to being ineffective at achieving the goal.