# What is the optimal Resolution setting to send raw photo from Capture One to Aurora

Tags: hdr, capture-one, fujifilm-x-t20

I am trying to send a group of raw photo from Capture One to Aurora in order to create a HDR image.

A dialog box pops up when I do so

[image]

I think most options are ok except 'Resolution': I am not sure if '300 px/in' is the right value. I am not entirely clear about the original resolution of the raw images (I am using a Fujifilm x-t20). I do not want to pass raw files to Aurora in lower resolution because of incorrect 'Resolution' value.

What is the optimal value for the Resolution field in this case? Since I am sending raw data from one application to another, I do not want to pick a value that may cause the downstream application to suffer from data loss.

Comment: The resolution in a photo is just an arbitrary number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the dpi number reported by camera in JPG have any meaning?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/does-the-dpi-number-reported-by-camera-in-jpg-have-any-meaning)

Comment: @ths The format in question is tiff. You quoted a Jpeg question.

Comment: the same reasoning applies.

Comment: @ths I have edited my question to clarify my intent. I am not asking a DPI question per se. I want to ensure there will be no data loss in this inter-application communication. Please take time to read and understand the question.

Comment: you might, in turn, want to read and understand the linked question. TLDR: DPI (=resolution in this dialog) is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Resolution" in this case has no effect on the exported quality.

If you intend to print, you *could* set this to the DPI of the printer, which could help making it easier later to get the size right when printing later.

The important option here is the "Scale" which you have currently set to Fixed: 100% - That means that the output will be the exact same resolution (measured in pixels) as the source.