# Calculate the maximum DPI a camera can shoot

Tags: camera-settings, resolution, dpi

I am trying to determine at what **DPI** a certain camera can shoot, namely  [this model](https://www.sony.com/electronics/cyber-shot-compact-cameras/dsc-w800/specifications), however the technical specs at the official site do not give any details about it.

Is there a way to calculate the maximum possible DPI a given camera can shoot provided we have the sensor type and its number of pixels (just as the in the link above) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the dpi number reported by camera in JPG have any meaning?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/does-the-dpi-number-reported-by-camera-in-jpg-have-any-meaning) - now I know it's not quite the same question, but the answer is the same - "DPI" is meaningless for a digital image.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think this question is not about the DPI in the image metadata, but about the pixels per unit of distance that you can achieve when you do macro photography, which is a combination of reproduction ratio and sensor definition. Just change "DPI" in the question to "pixels/mm".

Comment: @xenoid If that's the case, the poster can edit to clarify, it's certainly not obvious to me that's what they're after.

Answer (score 1):

This will get rapidly closed against the duplicate, but just to set this out in as simple a way as possible…

DPI has no meaning whatsoever until you need to print an image.
At that point, the image's printed size will depend on the DPI set at the moment it is sent to the printer. This is a variable.

All an image has before that is a size, dimensions in pixels.
Nothing else.

Comment: The EXIF "dpi" tag also has meaning if an image is imported into page setting software or even some text/document editors.

Comment: @Tetsujin,  thanks for your comments, but about your note "all the image has before that is a size, dimension in pixels" , isn't the **physical resolution** at which the camera can capture an image a parameter of the camera  ( the [optical dpi](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/optical_resolution.html)  ) ?

Comment: @Hayk You are linking to an article about optical resolution, not optical dpi. That is only a term you just invented. The article uses dpi in connection with scanners, where it makes sense, but not when it comes to cameras.

Comment: The 'DPI' of the sensor isn't related to the DPI of the image. The camera captures a number of pixels. If it does that on a full frame or crop frame will affect the "DPI" of the camera, but if they're both 24 MP, the resulting image will be the same 'size'. EXIF tagging being read by DTP software is merely a precursor to its being printed. Change the DPI number in the EXIF, the DTP will think it should be printed at a different size. The image, however, does not change at all.

Comment: @MichaelC If the image comes from a camera, the EXIF tag value for dpi does not have a meaning, even if a reading software tries to interpret it. Trying to use the dpi values in an image file makes only sense if the image comes from a capturing device, which knows the relationship between the pixel pitch and the physical size of the pictured object, e.g. when scanning a paper. In that case, the DPI values can e.g. be used to reproduce the image at the same size as the original.

Comment: It still has meaning, just not the same meaning as the dpi attached to a scanned image has. It's still a *meaningful* instruction regarding how the image should be printed, even if that instruction was assigned with very little or no thought on the part of who assigned it. It is *meaningful* because it will affect how the image appears in page setting applications and how large the image will print if the printing application/printer follows the embedded instructions.

Comment: @MichaelC In which case it is merely a printing instruction. The property still has no meaning related to, nor does it describe any inherent feature or trait of the image itself.

Comment: @jarnbjo I never said it has any meaning related to any inherent feature or trait of the image itself. I said that it has meaning that affects how it will be displayed in certain circumstances, and it does.