# Is there a photoshop plugin or any other piece of software that can do super resolution?

Tags: software, technique, resolution, plugin, superresolution

I want to combine multiple photographs of the same landscape to increase the resolution of the final image. More details on the method here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution

What software can I use to achieve this?

Comment: There is already a similar question, the answers would be similar at least. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17098/csi-image-resolution-enhance-how-real-is-it

Comment: [Super-Resolution software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9715/3579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check out:

http://almalence.com/doc/superresolution-comparison/

and the product:

http://www.photoacute.com/

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelsuperresolution) plugin for [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) will perform super-resolution processing but only for black-and-white images. I haven't used it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer in the very article you linked to - [Super Resolution GUI](http://www.ece.lsu.edu/ipl/Software.html) (under "External Links" on that wiki page).

Comment: Yes, but it's not a stand alone program (it's dependent of matlab ) and i couldn't make it work in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Photoshop CS6 extended version (or Photoshop CC).

1. Take multiple images of a object (or multiple frames of a video).
2. Open Photoshop, and go to **File > Scripts > Load files into stack**.
3. Select the stack you made in Step 1 and click on **Convert to smart object**.
4. Select **Layers > Smart Objects > Median**.
5. Enlarge the image by clicking **Image > Image Size**.

You will get a nice clean super resolution image result!