# how can I make the text visible in this photo

Tags: photoshop

[image]
Will someone help me make the text visible on this photo, or tell me how to? Please[image][image]

Comment: Instead of focusing on text, isn't there a barcode somewhere with the S/N on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSI image resolution enhance: How real is it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17098/csi-image-resolution-enhance-how-real-is-it)

Answer (score 3):

That's not going to happen, I'm afraid. Samsung 500T is all you're ever going to extract from that image.

Aside from the fact that it was shot in very low light with a flash, which has swamped a lot of it, it's also been sized up & perhaps sharpened from a much smaller image by the looks of it.
This will not gain any information. You cannot create information which is not actually there.

This is what's there, you cannot recreate what isn't.

[image]

There *might* be better information in the original of that photo, but there's none in that particular copy.

The only solution I can see is to take the photo again in good light, & preserve the image resolution.

See also - [CSI image resolution enhance: How real is it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17098/csi-image-resolution-enhance-how-real-is-it)

Comment: If taking another picture was an option I would. It was stolen. That's why I'm trying to figure out the serial number

Comment: That, I'm afraid, doesn't make that photo any more decipherable. See if you can find the original picture, before it was jpegged to oblivion & you may have more chance.

Comment: I think I found the original one

Comment: There's no more detail in either the original or the alternative image, unfortunately. You could talk to the guys at Amped [see the CSI link] to see if they could coax something out of both images combined, but even if it were possible it would probably cost more than a new laptop.

Comment: Ha I appreciate the help. The laptop is worth like $1,400  so honestly wouldn't care. Thank you

Comment: @AngelCutts Does your receipt/bill of sale include the serial number? Often items with that much value do. If you still have the box the computer came in, it almost certainly has the serial number on one of the stickers attached to the box.

Comment: I looked for it, it was purchased years ago, I also checked to see if the store would be able to bring up anything and they don't keep records that far back