# How to scale up an image for print. How large can i go?

Tags: printing, rescaling, dpi

I have an approximately 2500 pixel x 3500 pixel image. How do I figure out the largest print that I can get from it? At the 300 dpi printing standard that would only yield about 8x12" but I need something larger. Larger than A4.

Comment: The dpi field in the EXIF info is near meaningless. Whether it is set at 1, 72, 300, or 10,000 you still have a 2500x3500 pixel image. For more regarding this particular aspect of your question, please see: [Is there any practical difference between saving at 300ppi or 72ppi?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46671/is-there-any-practical-difference-between-saving-at-300ppi-or-72ppi)

Comment: Aslo: [Is it possible to scale up an image to increase the the pixel density?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12788/is-it-possible-to-scale-up-an-image-to-increase-the-the-pixel-density)

Comment: What will be your viewing distance? Depending on that 12 dpi might be enough if it's something like a billboard

Comment: And: [How does the resize option 'bicubic auto' in CS6 incrementally upscale images?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40737/how-does-the-resize-option-bicubic-auto-in-cs6-incrementally-upscale-images)

Comment: [Is there a general formula for image size vs. print size?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/456/is-there-a-general-formula-for-image-size-vs-print-size)

Comment: And the Big Kahuna of resolution vs. printing questions & answers: [How do I generate high quality prints with an ink jet printer?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-do-i-generate-high-quality-prints-with-an-ink-jet-printer/1716#1716)

Comment: I really appreciate your help

Comment: Oblig:  "Just click the ENHANCE button"

Answer (score 4):

Do the math.  If you really need 300 DPI, then at most your picture can be (2500 pixels)/(300 pixels/inch) = 8.3 inches wide.

If you want bigger than that you either can't, or you have to relax your resolution requirements.  200 DPI might still be good enough for something hand-held, for example.

The resolution the picture needs to have depends on viewing distance.  Let's say you've decided that 200 DPI is sufficient when viewed from 18 inches.  The minimum DPI you need is inversely proportional to distance.  If the print will be viewed from 6 feet away, for example, then it only needs to be printed at 50 DPI, which means it can be 50 inches wide.

Conversely, if the picture is for a billboard 20 feet wide, then you only get 10.4 DPI, and the viewer has to be 29 feet back to have it look like the 200 DPI print at 18 inches.