# How do you increase the amount of pixels in the width of your photo?

Tags: image-quality

I have taken a photo in early November using my iPad mini when the weather was still really nivpce and warm. I would hate to not show it because for once, I'm pretty proud of my photos. I'm trying to enter it into a contest, and it keeps saying that The width of the image needs to be greater than 2000 pixels. Help plz!

Comment: On an iPad, PC, Mac, other? Please define.

Comment: Generally if the contest requires the image to be a certain size, they do not want smaller images that have been resized to be larger. In fact, that is exactly the type of thing they are trying to avoid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upscale a low-res image to make it appear higher-res?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/how-can-i-upscale-a-low-res-image-to-make-it-appear-higher-res)

Comment: The iPad mini should take images at 2592×1936. That's either sufficient (landscape orientation) it just short (portrait orientation), unless you were using an app which reduces resolution — or using the front camera. Can you clarify?

Comment: @mattdm - That question assumes the OP has access to Photoshop.  Not sure that is the case.

Comment: I had a relative who was using some iProduct to send photos as email attachments, and persistently sent out very small (~320x240) image files, even though the full-size versions certainly existed somewhere in local or cloud storage. Whatever method they were using to access the photos was providing them with low-resolution copies. You may want to consider this angle, rather than attempting to enlarge a small copy.

Answer (score 9):

In this case the answer is most likely *"You don't"*.

This contest is apparently specifying a minimum width of 2000 pixels to weed out pictures from less serious cameras, like yours.  Having you submit a picture is exactly what they are trying to avoid.

Read the rules carefully.  They probably specify that the picture must have *native* size of 2000 pixels or more across.  While you can resize any picture to 2000 pixels across, that's not what they want, and is probably violating their rules.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using XnViewMP for that.

1. Open you photo in XnViewMP
2. Pick "Image->Canvas resize" from top menu
3. Add equal number of pixels to both width and height
4. Adjust background color for your preference

This way you will get a small border and won't loose image quality. Use "File->Format settings" to set JPEG quality.

You can also resize your image but I suggest that you add a small border instead because you will loose quality that way.

Comment: This is probably not what the contest wants, and possibly against the rules.  If you're going to give this kind of advice, the first thing should be to read the rules of the contest carefully.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: the question is not about dealing with contests, it is about compensating for slight shortage of resolution. I know it is critical for photographers to keep high economic entry barriers for photography but I do not think that it is critical enough to suggest that one cannot/shouldn't use 1936px wide image when 2000px is requested. If resolution is co critical why is it given with a multiple of power of ten? If they were so picky, why did not they say "2011px"? There is little insight in chosing multiples of power of ten with some rare exceptions.

Comment: No, this is exactly about how to cheat contest rules.  We don't know why they specified 2000 pixels minimum, but they did.  It is what it is.  Just because 1936 pixels is almost 2000, and in a genuine usage case they are effectively equivalent, doesn't make cheating right.  The contest has the right to set their rules as they like, whether you or I think they are sensible or not.  We have the right not to enter and to go somewhere else.  What we *don't* have the right to do is to deliberately violate the rules of something that was completely our choice to participate in.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: "What we don't have the right to do is to deliberately violate the rules" - is it backed up by some law? If not, it is protectionism. If authors cared about quality they would set the rule to accept no photos without EXIF and prohibit every mobile phone camera with small enough sensor (because, you know, 20mp tiny sensor is still usually worse than 6MP large one because of optics). Your answer implies some hidden restrictions, ethics and prohibition of borders (it is unrealistic, try to find contests which prohibits borders), my answer is about the question as it is asked.

Comment: We don't know the full contest rules in this case. If they ask for unmodified images, I agree that upscaling would be out of line. If they allow modifications, though, a 3% change might be okay — you might get similar that from lens distortion or perspective correction, for example. Does the restriction apply to the image as captured, or to the result?

Answer (score 0):

If you have taken more than one picture of that scene then you can use the panorama stitcher [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net) to create a panorama. Whether or not this will work and yield a nice result, depends on whether there is enough overlap between the different pictures.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't about quality, it's about quantity. I have seen marvellous smart phone photos (in fact, building-size). You can simply increase your image size in your favourite editor if it's merely more pixels that you want. This may not look too good for pixel-peepers, but viewed from a greater distance it may be just fine.