# Too low DPI for canvas

Tags: dpi, canvas

For my mom's birthday we had a photoshoot with the grandchildren. The photo we would like to print on a canvas is 3530 x 2353 and the desired size is 140 cm x 93.3 cm. Now the software says that the DPI is too low.
Can somebody please help? 
Is there a way to change the DPI or is the quality of the photo just too low for the size? That would be a pity, because we payed a lot for these professional photographs.

Greetings, 
Silke

Comment: Are you sure those dimensions are correct? 933cm is over 9metres wide, that's bigger than most rooms. At that size almost any photo would be insufficient DPI.

Comment: Even if it is 140x933 mm (nearly one meter),  3530 pixels and 933 mm works out to only 96 dpi.  But... a much bigger problem, the image and the canvas are extremely different shapes. The image aspect ratio is 3:2, but the canvas is 6.66:1.  On this canvas, it could only print  210x140mm without very substantial cropping. This is probably the wrong "shape" to attempt to print this photo.  The image is NOT the same shape as the canvas.

Comment: 3530 x 2353 is only about 8MP. Most current "pro" cameras shoot at upwards of 18-20MP. Have you asked the photographer if a higher resolution version of the image is available?

Answer (score 1):

Conserving the height/width ratio, you are asking about a 140 x 93.3 cm print. Your image, with a definition of 3530x2353 = 8 MP will yield a DPI of about 64. This isn't enough in my opinion to get a print of good quality.

With such a definition, I wouldn't hope for more than 100 x 66 cm. With a *standard* 150 DPI (to take into account distance of viewing), a *good* print size would be about 60 x 40 cm. Those numbers are only given as indication and depends on the image, but they are generally working for me.

Now, you can try to increase your definition. As some images are better suited than other, you have to try and see.

Take a look at :

- [How can I upscale a low-res image to make it appear higher-res?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/how-can-i-upscale-a-low-res-image-to-make-it-appear-higher-res)
- [How do I generate high quality prints with an ink jet printer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-do-i-generate-high-quality-prints-with-an-ink-jet-printer)
- [Is it possible to scale up an image to increase the the pixel density?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12788/is-it-possible-to-increase-scale-up-an-image-to-increase-the-the-pixel-density)

Answer (score 0):

The DPI is not very high, but sometimes images come out surprisingly nice even with low DPI. I'd suggest that if the cost of the print is not prohibitive, that you try and see how the result looks like. If it is too bad for the expected viewing distance, reprint smaller with target size of 150 pixels per inch.

Also, if you are willing to do a little bit of tweaking, consider using Perfect Resize to resample the image to higher DPI. They have a free trial, btw.