# Resizing photos after editing

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing

I have a question concerning resizing files after editing in Lightroom or Photoshop

*scenario*: 1 RAW file of 23MB (a portrait foto - as an example) customer wants a big poster of the photo 60 x 90 CM,

Can it be resized in Lightroom/ photoshop for a print of that size? For instance I save it in "Tif" format. Instead of the default size of 1000 x 1000 with a pixel density of 240 per inch I want to save it as 3000 x 6000, density 320 per inch. Is this possible?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in your definition of "size". What is the original image size? 1000x1000 would be unusual. & why do you think you need 320 dpi for the final image? What has the printer requested? 90cm is approx 35". 6000px @ 320dpi is approx 18". None of the numbers add up.

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can interpolate up. Longer answer: involves knowing just how far you can push an image, what the viewing distance is, and when the two will combine to cause a crap print.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to scale up an image to increase the the pixel density?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12788/is-it-possible-to-scale-up-an-image-to-increase-the-the-pixel-density)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but you have a lot of things mixed and confused.

- The Raw file weight is not important at all.
- There is no default size of 1000x1000. The default size is the one directly produced by your camera, for example, 24 Mpx. Which is 6000x4000px.

If you want a print 60x90 you need a photo of a proportion 6:9 or 2:3 which is the same, in this case as 4000x6000px.

- Again why you want to change the proportion arbitrary to 3000x6000... It has no sense.

---

Let me explore a 24 Mpx file.

For a print of 60x90 you get right out the box:

6000px/90cm = 66.6px/cm or 170PPI, which is pretty good resolution It will be sharper than a normal magazine print. I would leave it like this.

But still, you can interpolate it to exactly double the size to maximize the resampling, and then applying some sharpening to get a file 340PPI more than enough for a high-quality print.