# Technical photography digital printing book?

Tags: digital, printing, books

I want to learn more about photography digital printing.
For me, the transformation of *virtual* pixels (existing only in the binary format) into something *real* is still complex :

- A lots of support exists : papers (mate/glossy, (un)coated,...), frames (aluminium/Dibond, plexiglass, plastic,... )
- The technologies of a printer are complex and change with the support (continuous/drop on demand, thermal/piezoelectric, solid ink, UV...)
- Plenty of different algorithms are used : halftoning, dithering, interpolation...

What technical books can you recommend ? (I have bought and partially read "[Mastering Digital Printing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592004318)" but it seems a little outdated, 2005)

Comment: Not a book, but it is *almost* book length. LOL    http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-do-i-generate-high-quality-prints-with-an-ink-jet-printer

Comment: @MichaelClark, It's indeed a great answer from jrista (read it multiple times already), but far from complete regarding digital print. I know a lot of nice answers about printing are on SE, but I'm really looking for a book. Maybe we can ask jrista to publish one

Comment: Sharpening is a big part of this. Best ref is Bruce Fraser, Real World Image Sharpening with Adobe Photoshop CS2. That's right CS2; Fraser died after publishing this book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because list questions are really a bad fit for the site. Basically, they don't get good maintenance and are generally shopping oriented, something we tend to discourage.