# Why there is a ripple on my image?

Tags: image-quality

I'm taking several images of my company products, and [this is](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxfSalWxGooPNmhJa0t5YXpsYnM) what I considered the best shot. However, it has a sort of "rippling effect", which is more clearly visible when it's not viewed full screen.

[image]

Why does this happened?

I'm taking the picture using a 15 mp smartphone camera, if that helps.

Comment: You are probably experiencing "moire", or the effects of repeating patterns. If the full size image does not demonstrate moire, then you are likely seeing scaling errors that can also produce moire like effects.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to fix the wavy lines that appear when photographing a striped dress?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69665/is-there-any-way-to-fix-the-wavy-lines-that-appear-when-photographing-a-striped)

Comment: see https://photographylife.com/what-is-moire/ for an explanation, keep in mind that any picture is made up out of pixels. Usually for photos you would downscale your picture on the screen so multiple pixels in the photo are mapped onto one pixel of your monitor. By zooming in to 100% you will get a picture that is more in line with what your picture would look like when printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [Moire pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) and is created by the regular lines of the tiles in the photo interacting with the black grid between the pixels of any computer monitor.